# Is there a first-time home buyer index?

Tags: data-request

Is there a first-time home buyer index? Specifically, I would like to know the number of first-time purchases in the U.S. in an annual time series. Strictly speaking such an index should not differentiate between single family detached homes and multi-unit residential homes. Strictly speaking such an index should not differentiate between purchases of existing homes and new builds.